# ArcGIS geocoding suggestion service, max suggestion number

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

How do I set the maximum number of suggestions returned by ArcGIS suggestion service to more than the default 5? 
In the docs ([docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-suggest.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_606D93C721874B16844B9AB9CA8083FF)) they say,

> "maximum number allowed by the service".

So I believe, that this is a thing you could change.

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.3.1.
Here is a sample from the docs with more than 5 suggestions [link](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=esri&maxSuggestions=8&f=pjson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "maxSuggestions" parameter for the Geocode REST Service was added in 10.4.

Since you are using 10.3.1, there may not be a way to control it.

See parameter details [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Suggest/02r30000029p000000/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in ArcGIS Online: go to the application hosting the services, select the search Widget.
[image]

Comment: this is a workaround since you're using 10.3